# FileObserver.MODIFY event caught just after FileObserver.CREATE

Tags: android, android-intent, fileobserver

Whenever a new photo is created (i.e. a new photo is clicked from a camera intent) in the directory I am monitoring, the `onEvent` method first catches the `FileObserver.CREATE` event, and immediately after that, it catches `FileObserver.MODIFY` event. Why is it catching the `FileObserver.MODIFY` event? Is it some sort of bug, or it always happens like this?

Comment: when the file is created it has the length of zero

Comment: So whenever a new photo is created, both of these events will be triggered one by one, right? @pskink

Comment: i think it is quite normal way... otherwise what would `CREATE` be used for?

Comment: When FileObserver.CREATE event is caught, the size of the file is not zero, as suggested by the debugger. @pskink

Comment: FileObserver works in async way so the notification can be delayed i think